# Rails 3: Uniqueness validation for nested fields_for - Part2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to coding - and have not enough reputation to comment this answer:
[Rails 3: Uniqueness validation for nested fields_for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5482777/rails-3-uniqueness-validation-for-nested-fields-for/10641150#10641150)

So I am creating this question as "Part 2" :)

I am a web designer but curious to learn coding, held with this from my days.

```
# app/validators/nested_attributes_uniqueness_validator.rb   
class NestedAttributesUniquenessValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
        record.errors[attribute] << "Products names must be unique" unless value.map(&:name).uniq.size == value.size
      end
end
```

above code with "ActiveModel::EachValidator" throw this error:

"undefined method `map' for "Area 1":String"

---

```
# app/validators/nested_attributes_uniqueness_validator.rb   
class NestedAttributesUniquenessValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
    record.errors[attribute] << "Products names must be unique" unless value.map(&:name).uniq.size == value.size
  end
end
```

above code with "ActiveModel::Validator" throw this error:

"Subclasses must implement a validate(record) method. "

---

this is model file:

```
class Area < ActiveRecord::Base


  validates :name,
            :presence => true,
            :uniqueness => {:scope => :city_id},
            :nested_attributes_uniqueness => {:field => :name}

  belongs_to :city

end
```

---

You can find complete code over here:
https://github.com/syed-haroon/rose

Comment: Those validator classes look really weird - you're doing your check directly in the class rather than in appropriate instance method (as the other question you link to does)

Comment: You've got different code in the repo for the validator than what you show here .. did you get it working?

Comment: also i think you need to change this line https://github.com/syed-haroon/rose/blob/master/config/application.rb#L19 to include the `"#{Rails.root}/app/validators"` folder

Comment: First of all, thanks to start supporting this issue:
Yes its true that there is little changes in the files that i have committed and the code that i have showed here. Now there is no difference - pls check my repo.

Comment: @syed: I dont see any nested attributes in your model, though you are validating it (nested_attributes_uniqueness). As Alberto mentioned in the answer to your parent question

# app/models/shop.rb
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :products, :products_name_uniqueness => true
end
There should be 2 models which are associated like shops has many products, here in your code i dont see 2 models like that. hence it will be nice if you talk about what really you want to achieve so that i can tell you how to do it in rails way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer over here :

https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2160-nested_attributes-validates_uniqueness_of-fails

&

[validates_uniqueness_of in destroyed nested model rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772236/validates-uniqueness-of-in-nested-model-rails)

This is for rails 2, one line need to me modified over here:
`add_to_base` has been deprecated and is unavailable in 3.1. Use `self.errors.add(:base, message)`

Answer (score 1):

@Syed: I think you are trying to do this. else reply to my comment.

```
# app/models/city.rb
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :areas
  validates :areas, :area_name_uniqueness => true
end

# app/models/area.rb
class Area < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :name  
end

# config/initializers/area_name_uniqueness_validator.rb
class AreaNameUniquenessValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    record.errors[attribute] << "Area names must be unique" unless value.map(&:name).uniq.size == value.size
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi @Krishnaprasad, thanks for helping out buddy and nice to meet you in stackoverflow :)

I tried the way you mentioned about, but its throwing this error:

"Subclasses must implement a validate(record) method."

anyhow i have not committed that into my git repo. If you find time can you take a look into it.